# React Native ListView TextInput locks up from performance optimization rendering

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, listview, react-native

I am trying to set a state value for each textinput contained in each row of my listview.

The issue is that, React Native's ListView Component has a bunch of optimization techniques such as removing rows that are out of screen bounds. This is causing an issue because the TextInputs are locking up their value property, editing them will no longer reflect changes and the state value locks up or something. I've attached a video to show this behavior.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fq7ITtzRvg4&feature=youtu.be

```
    _renderRow(value){
    let tempWidth = window.width / 2.13
    if(value.data.length == 1){
        tempWidth = window.width*0.970
    }
    var Images =  value.data.map((b,i) => {
        let source = { uri: BUCKETIMAGES+'/'+b.image_filename}
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity key={i} style={styles.cardImage}>
                {b.profile_picture &&
                <View style={{zIndex: 4, width:31,height:31,borderWidth:1,borderColor:"#ccc",borderRadius:20, position: "absolute", right: -6, top: -6}}>
                    <CacheableImage style={{width:30,height:30,borderWidth:3,borderColor:"white",borderRadius:15,position: "absolute", right: 0, top: 0}} source={{uri: BUCKETIMAGES+'/'+b.profile_picture}}/>
                </View>
                }
                <CacheableImage source={source} style={{height: 150, width: tempWidth}}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    });
    return(
            <View key={value.id} style={styles.statusContainer}>
                 <View style={[styles.statusHeader,{height: 50, alignItems: "center"}]}>
                    <View style={{flex:0.85}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}> 
                                <Text style={{color: "#666666", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 18, paddingLeft: 20}}>Team {value.type}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <Text style={{color: "grey", fontSize: 15, paddingLeft: 20, paddingRight: 20}}>{value.date}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:0.15,height: 20, justifyContent: "center",width: 30}}>
                            <Icon name="ios-more" type="ionicon" size={40} color="#a9a9a9" />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={{flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
                    { Images }
                </View>
                <View style={{zIndex: 10}}>

                </View>
                <View style={[styles.commentHeader,{height: 30,flex:0.8, zIndex: 5}]}>
                    <View style={{height: 30, width: 40}}>
                            <Icon name="ios-chatboxes-outline" type="ionicon" size={30} color="grey" />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex:0.9}}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.commentInput}
                                placeholder="Say something..."
                                placeholderTextColor="gray"
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                multiline={true}
                                blurOnSubmit={true}
                                value={this.state['comment'+value.id]}
                                onChangeText={(commentInput) => {this.setState({["comment"+value.id]: commentInput})}}
                            />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{justifyContent: "center", marginRight: 20}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({commentID: value.id}, this.addComment)}}>
                            <Icon name="md-send" type="ionicon" size={25} color="#CCC" />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>    
            </View>
    )
}

render() {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {Platform.OS === "ios" &&
            <View style={styles.statusBar}></View>
            }
            {this.state.loading &&
            <ActivityIndicator
                animating={true}
                color="#E91E63"
                size="large"
                style={{marginTop: 80}}
            />
            }
            {!this.state.loading &&
            <ListView
                    dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow  = {this._renderRow.bind(this)}
                    initialListSize={10}
                    enableEmptySections={true}
            />}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try using FlatList, if you're on a recent enough version of react-native.  http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html "No more ListViews or DataSources, stale rows"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a component to render each row so each item can hold its own state. I've done something similar with 500+ rows with a ListView and it worked well.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your bounty will be given in 6 hours

Answer (score 1):

With react-native `0.45.1`, I quickly made this mock up with 1000 rows and the TextInput works fine. It doesn't lock up like in your demo....even if you scroll all the way down to the end and back up, the `TextInput` state is proper, and still editable.

I suggest starting with this model, and build up your implementation to see where it breaks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';


const mocks = []
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  mocks.push({
    id:i,
    text: `I am row ${i}`
  })
}


export default class test extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2 })
    this.state = {
      ds: this.ds.cloneWithRows(mocks),
    }
  }

  renderRow = (value) => {
    return(
      <View style={ styles.rowContainer }>
        <Text>{ value.text }</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={ styles.textInput }
          value={ this.state[`comment${value.id}`] }
          onChangeText={ (text) => this.setState({ [`comment${value.id}`]:text }) }
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}> 
        <ListView
          dataSource={ this.state.ds }
          renderRow={ this.renderRow }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  rowContainer:{
    padding:10,
    marginBottom:10,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(222,222,222)'
  },
  textInput:{
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 50,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => test);
```